# Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions again

Tags: sql, database, symfony, naming, convention

Although this topic has been touched many times I write about it again to share my experiences. Before starting the project I was looking for a naming convention for database and read the advice that I found on this website. I used the convention Pascal or Camel if you prefer.

```
MyTable
MyColumnName
```

Firstly, it turned out that the project is unportable as databases write data in the directories with names coming from the names of the tables, and a variety of operating systems have different interpretation of lowercase and capital letters in the names of files and directories.
I changed convention to lowercase underscore naming convention.

```
my_table
my_column_name
```

It seemed that the problem is solved, but not quite.
There is another problem: the keywords.
Here is an [excerpt](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1802) discussing which I came across when I recognized the problem in my project. In short Frameworks don't quote keywords because it reduces database performance.
So another convention change.

```
_my_table
_my_column_name
_reserved_keyword
```

My question is: How many changes to the naming convention was waiting for me?
I hope this post will help others overcome the problems with which I had to face.

Comment: Pascal and Camel are different. Pascal has an initial upper case character, Camel has a lower case initial character. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I don't think quoting identifiers reduce performance, do you have any evidence? Obviously this depends on the implementation of the engine

Comment: I don't care about discussion of performance of database but this has really impact of my performance.

Comment: I'm not sure about others (although I assume they are similar) but with Doctrine you can set the field name as `Date` and then set the actual column name for the DB to whatever you want like `item_date` to avoid any keywords issues. They aren't the same name (obviously) but it does mean you don't have to start going through weird conventions.

Comment: Sure. Long time ago I wrote my own framework, I can do whatever I like but This what I want just now is fast way to deploy application.

Comment: I think I agree with @Qoop, the choice of framework should not impose any additional limitation on the naming of database objects. My team and I use Pascal Case for our database objects and Upper Case for our keywords. The framework quotes all identifiers so it doesn't actually matter if there is a naming clash. If the quoted identifiers cause a performance issue I suspect the internal workings of the framework will have a far greater impact. I'd suggest this is a fail for Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

Naming convention isn't a must, its only an recommendation. You should wisely specify the table, column, etc. names, thinking about them as there were no naming conventions. 
Do not use reserved words, non-alphabetical chars, etc. and your problem is gone.